# what's the difference between androidx and android support library?

Tags: android

I read the doucument, and I found one of the difference is that androidx use a strict semantic versioning. there are any others? I wanna know the understandable difference between androidx and android support library

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between androidx and com.android.support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50338323/difference-between-androidx-and-com-android-support)

Comment: For more clerification you laso refer this article :- https://www.quora.com/What-is-AndroidX-What-is-the-difference-between-Android-and-AndroidX